# Float precision in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a ruby program that uses floats.  I'm having trouble with the precision.  For example

```
1.9.3p194 :013 > 113.0 * 0.01
# => 1.1300000000000001
```

and therefore

```
1.9.3p194 :018 > 113 * 0.01 == 1.13
# => false
```

This is exactly the sort of calculation my app needs to get right.

Is this expected?  How should I go about handling this?

Comment: Remember that if you are trying to count money then use integers instead of floats. That's BTW.

Comment: Thanks for the btw.  It isn't money, the values are the results of calculations, so they aren't restricted to discrete increments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an inherent limitation in floating point numbers (even 0.01 doesn't have an exact binary floating point representation). You can use the technique provided by Aleksey or, if you want perfect precision, use the BigDecimal class bundled in ruby. It's more verbose, and slower, but it will give the right results:

```
require 'bigdecimal'
=> true
1.9.3p194 :003 > BigDecimal.new("113") * BigDecimal("0.01")
=> #<BigDecimal:26cefd8,'0.113E1',18(36)> 
1.9.3p194 :004 > BigDecimal.new("113") * BigDecimal("0.01") == BigDecimal("1.13")
=> true
```

Comment: This looks like the way.  I'll suffer the performance and code elegance hit.

Comment: Using `Rational` is also a possibility.

Comment: You can always make an utility class/functions to spare yourself the extra coding. Something like `Money.add(a,b)` which encapsulates the `BigDecimal` boilerplate. It's what I am doing in my projects and it helps a lot on the code readability.

Answer (score 2):

In calculation with float you should use sigma method - it means not to compare two values, but compare absolute difference of them with a very little value - 1e-10, for example.

```
((113 * 0.01) - 1.13).abs<1e-10
```

Comment: Thanks.  This tells me that I probably shouldn't be using Float here.