# Odd output behavior with Ruby on OS X

Tags: ruby, precision, rounding-error

I have a simple program written in Ruby. The code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

# odd behavior here
j = 1.11
while j < 2
    print "iteration #{j}\n"
    j += 0.01
end
```

I am running it on a MacBook Air with Mountain Lion. My version of Ruby is:

```
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
```

The odd behavior I'm seeing is:

```
iteration 1.1
iteration 1.11
iteration 1.12
iteration 1.1300000000000001
iteration 1.1400000000000001
```

Now if I change j to 1.13, I get the following resutls (I'm removing some of the output for the sake of brevity):

```
iteration 1.13
iteration 1.14
iteration 1.15
...
iteration 1.36
iteration 1.37
iteration 1.3800000000000001
iteration 1.3900000000000001
iteration 1.4000000000000001
iteration 1.4100000000000001
iteration 1.4200000000000002
```

What is going on here? Initially, I thought maybe it had something to do with how the values were stored in j and that 1.13 has some special attribute. However, starting j at 1.13 turned that theory on its head. What's really getting me is that this doesn't seem to be consistent. In other words, it seems somewhat arbitrary (although I'm sure it's not) where the odd "0000000000"s come into play.

To make matters worse, if I change the "j < 2" to "j < 5" I get even stranger behavior.

```
...
iteration 4.85999999999994
iteration 4.86999999999994
iteration 4.8799999999999395
iteration 4.889999999999939
iteration 4.899999999999939
iteration 4.909999999999939
iteration 4.919999999999939
iteration 4.929999999999938
iteration 4.939999999999938
iteration 4.949999999999938
iteration 4.959999999999938
iteration 4.969999999999938
iteration 4.979999999999937
iteration 4.989999999999937
iteration 4.999999999999937
```

I've tried Googling this but to be honest, I'm not really sure where to start. I've found a few threads where people are seeing odd behavior with to_d but nothing that specifically answers my question. Additionally, I don't know enough about Ruby to fully understand what's going on. It's got to be an issue with precision and how Ruby stores numbers, but I'm not sure where to look.

Any nudges in the right direction are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Float precision in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541907/float-precision-in-ruby)

Comment: It shows that `0.01` is not precisely stored as `0.01` inside Ruby. This is due to rounding error, as you tagged. The error is smaller than `0.0000000000000001`, so it does not show up in the first few additions, but after a few additions of it, the error accumulates and, together with the rounding error of `1.11`, it reaches `0.0000000000000001` so that starts to appear.

Comment: @sawa Thanks! Very informative post and great link. Should have found that myself...

Answer (score 0):

The numbers you see fall within the epsilon defined in limits.h: 2.2204460492503131e-16

In other words, the calculations are OK, it's the display that thinks it's a more precise number than it is. That's my best guess.

I looked at the sprintf.c in the ruby source code. It appears to convert floats into BigDecimal:

```
    switch (TYPE(val)) {
      case T_FLOAT:
        if (FIXABLE(RFLOAT_VALUE(val))) {
        val = LONG2FIX((long)RFLOAT_VALUE(val));
        goto bin_retry;
        }
        // THIS IS THE CONVERSION
        val = rb_dbl2big(RFLOAT_VALUE(val));
        if (FIXNUM_P(val)) goto bin_retry;
        bignum = 1;
        break;
```

This might be the cause of the odd display. However, a ruby double is a C double AFAIK, so the calculations should be the same as they are in c, except they look weird.

Try this c program, you'll get my meaning. You should get extraneous .000...1s which match up with your ruby results:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
double j;

j = 1.1;

while (j < 2) {
    printf ( "iteration %1.16f\n", j);
    j += 0.01;
    }
}
```

By the way, ruby 1.8.7 doesn't exhibit this behavior. Just a side note.